# How were the maze walls and ground suddenly intact again?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-maze-runner

We see in the **Maze Runner**(2014)  that when **Minho** and **Thomas** had found a way out of the maze, the maze started collapsing around them and they only just survived. 
The maze was throwing currents of ripped up concrete everywhere as shown below:

[image: Maze collapsing in that particular sector]

So, the very next day when half the **Glade** was wiped out from the Grievers, there aren't very many Gladers left, so... Thomas put up an offer to the other Gladers (as well as **Teresa**) to get out of the maze and most of the main Gladers went with him.

When they were going through exactly the same sector of the maze, the maze walls were fully intact, no dust anywhere and not so much as a crack or broken chunk of concrete.

**How is this possible in less than 24 hours?**

Please note: (the Gladers got out in less than 24 hours after discovery of the exit) and for the fact that the kill of the glade from the grievers went for most of the night and would have had to go back to the griever hole and regenerate, so **how did that maze sector become intact again**?

Comment: In the book, parts of the maze were optical illusions.  There is nothing I can remember from that scene in the movie where the entire collapse of the maze couldn't have been an optical illusion.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the walls crashing down was just meant to be an attack from the inner maze itself because the greivers were not around. The maze was trying to stop them completing it so tryed to attack them. I know this might not make any sense but it's a story after all of a mysterious maze...